# Scroll Counter - _.debouce fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, underscore.js, counter

**My problem**

I created a counter meant to raise or lower by one each time that the user scrolls up or down. The problem is that my counter

```
$('html').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if (delta < 0) {
        --count;
        transitionScreen(count);
        //$('h1').text ('You scrolled down');

    } else if (delta > 0 && count < 0) {
        ++count;
        transitionScreen(count);
        //$('h1').text ('You scrolled up');
    }
});
```

is incrementing multiple times by the scroll.

**the solution**

So someone suggested underscore.js's [debounce function](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to keep my counter function from being executed more than once per a given amount of time.

**The problem is me not knowing exactly how to implement the solution:**

Can someone help me use _.debounce with this function? I'm looking at the examples but don't exactly understand how to use it here. I'm new to javascript and picking it up very quickly, so any help will be much appreciated.

**Documentation clipping**

Debounce is used like this in documentation:

```
debounce_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])
```

And here's an example of the useage:

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
$(window).resize(lazyLayout);
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: Ah, ok great. I was trying to be too complicated and put the arguments into a variable as with the example. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Keep it simple :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('html').on('mousewheel', _.debounce(function(e){
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if (delta < 0) {
        --count;
        transitionScreen(count);
        //$('h1').text ('You scrolled down');

    } else if (delta > 0 && count < 0) {
        ++count;
        transitionScreen(count);
        //$('h1').text ('You scrolled up');
    }
}, 250));
```

That's  it.  Just like it's shown, instead of passing your function in, you pass in the result of the `_.debounce` function.

Comment: Be careful with that. On laptops trackpad (and Apple magic mouse or laptops) the `mousewheel` event will be fired tents of times for each scrolling. Between 50 and 100 times usually!!! The counter will increase 50 units at once!

Comment: @Alvaro: That's exactly what `debounce` is preventing.  No matter how many times the event is triggered, the function will only run once (250ms after the last event was triggered).

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh I see, it is using a `setTimeout`... interesting... but still can generate unwanted increases of the variable as you can not predict the scrolling time. Which may very easily change from 300 milliseconds to 700 or even more depending on the speed the user moves his fingers. After that time, if the user is ending to scroll, the counter will increase by tens.

Comment: @Alvaro: You mean if the user is scrolling too slowly?  I can see that.  That could be an issue.  There is also [`throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) that might be better here.  It's slightly different.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't see why that one should work either. The problem still being the same. If you set a `wait` of `400` milliseconds and the user is scrolling for 800 milliseconds, then the counter will be increasing twice and not one. (not tens as I said before, my mistake).

Comment: @Alvaro have you found a better solution for apple trackpads? please help ;)

Comment: @gregmatys just adding a delay. Scrolling only once every 600 milliseconds. Ignore the rest of scrollings.

Comment: @Alvaro But you wrote that duration depends on user finger's speed :) Doesn't trackpad emits events longer than 600ms?

Comment: @gregmatys yeah, you can be emitting scroll events for longer than that, but based on my experience usually people don't scroll longer than 600 or 700 milliseconds. 
In Apple devices there's also some kind of inertia. If you scroll very fast, even for less than 600 milliseconds, the scrolling event will be fired even after that time. But its quite improbable that someone scroll that fast anyway.

Comment: @Alvaro I'm not satisfied ;)

Comment: @gregmatys so whenever you find a solution let me know :D